# Django 1.6 - silent login fail after explicit login and redirect

Tags: django

We have a custom backend which returns the user object.

In a admin login view, we login on behalf of the user:

```
user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
login(request, user)

return redirect('/')
```

Here is what happens after a login:

```
[05/Dec/2013 13:23:04] "POST /adminlogin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[05/Dec/2013 13:23:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[05/Dec/2013 13:23:04] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 892
```

This used to work before we updated Django, we thought it might be related to [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12233), but cannot figure it out.

Comment: I had a similar symptoms when upgrading from 1.5.1 to 1.6.1:
Removed from django.contrib import admin and admin.autodiscover() from urls.py

Answer (score 0):

Have you called [authenticate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) first? From [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) in the docs:

> When you’re manually logging a user in, you must call `authenticate()` before you call `login()`. `authenticate()` sets an attribute on the `User` noting which authentication backend successfully authenticated that user (see the backends documentation for details), and this information is needed later during the login process.

Depending on your requirements, you may also need to provide a custom authentication backend and add it to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in your settings.py.